# How to change name of node (folder or document) with the Alfresco Mobile SDK for Android?

Tags: android, alfresco, setter

I would like to change the name of a node on the **Alfresco** server.

I am using the **Alfresco Mobile SDK for Android** and the documentation furnished on the website. I found without difficulty to have the name of the node : getName(), but there is no method for setName(), I would like to know a way to set a name for a node.

Maybe this function is useful, but I don't enough how to use the map of properties:

```
public Node updateProperties(Node node, Map<String, Serializable> properties)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call that method with the Node and something like the following:

```
 Map<String, Serializable> properties = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
 properties.put(ContentModel.PROP_NAME, "nodename");

 // like this:
 documentFolderService.updateProperties(myNode, properties);
```